# STM32L4S9 low temperature FLASH memory programming

Tags: stm32, temperature, flash, reliability

As there is no information on the internet I hope that I will not have any problems (as there are no complaints :) ).

My device will receive OTA updates and my question is:

Did you have any problems programming the FLASH memory in low temperatures (-25°C to -35°C)? I am running the test now, but I can only test one or two devices. I also can't test in a prolonged period of time. What is your experience with low-temperature FLASH memory reliability?

Comment: What does the manufacturer guarantee?

Comment: Relying on the experience of other users is a bad idea. The manufacturer is free to change the design or manufacturing process at any time as long as the device still meets its specifications. The **only** evidence you can rely on is the manufacturer's datasheet or similar documentation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson evidence + real-life experience. I am asking for the latter.

Comment: But someone else's "real-life experience" does not mean anything to you. The parts you have in hand may not work like that other person's parts, unless the manufacturer has specified them accordingly.